# Cloud Functions for Firebase - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, firebase, paypal, dns, google-cloud-functions

Trying to make a request to Paypal's API using [PayPal-node-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK)

```
exports.requestPayment = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return new Promise(function (fullfilled, rejected) {
        paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, {}, function (error, payment) {
            if (error) {
                rejected(error);
            } else {
                console.log("Create Payment Response");
                console.log(payment);
                res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({
                    paymentID: payment.id
                })).end();
                fullfilled(payment);
            }
        });
     });
});
```

but I'm constantly getting an error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sandbox.paypal.com api.sandbox.paypal.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

Things I've tried:

1. Making a request to a totally different host, still `ENOTFOUND`
2. Wrapping the request with `cors(req,res, ()=>{...})`
3. Prepending `https://` to the host

What is the problem?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You'll need to be on a paid plan to make external API requests.

Firebase's Blaze plan (pay as you go) has a free allotment for Cloud Functions. https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: Any reference to it? I have the same issue and before I make a purchase I'd like to know for sure that it's the issue.

Comment: You should see warnings on your function logs + it's probably buried on the pricing page somewhere. BTW I'm a DevRel on Cloud Functions for Firebase ;)

Comment: Footnote 3: The Spark plan only allows outbound network requests to Google owned services. On the Blaze plan, Cloud Functions provides a perpetual free tier.

Comment: Thanks for details! Really appreciate it. Once I pulled out my creditcard it worked just as expected!

Comment: Is this the same for a call to api hosted on another project's cloud function? I am getting `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` error when I do isomorphic-fetch to `https://us-central1-joanne-lee.cloudfunctions.net/getUrls/portrait`

Comment: I had a problem accessing `script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec`. I circumvented the limitation using the Apps Script API. It's conceivable you can call external resources in Apps Script, and then use Firebase to call the Apps Script. See https://gist.github.com/dan1wang/baf25ff2a45e6c53880e89185b0f29da

Comment: When comparing the The Blaze Plan prices you may see some small fees of around 10 cents for millions or thousands of calls, but actually you get to use up the Spark plans free quota before you're even using the blaze plan quotas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45683767/does-firebase-blaze-plan-have-the-spark-plans-quota#answer-45684576

Comment: after I upgraded to the blaze plan, my application is now able to make external calls

Comment: @SeanMC: Thanks for that good information. Now when developing I can just switch to Blaze plan and don't need to care about this issue

Comment: I chose blaze plan, even after that I am seeing same error. helloWorld: Function execution started
2020-04-04T20:46:07.525152372Z D helloWorld: Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited.

Comment: I am in blaze plan and also have billing enabled, but it still throw this error randomly.

Answer (score 3):

in my situation I had to wait and let what ever lag was happening pass.  Now it's fine again.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue because of weak internet, change the internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include service account to the admin initialization. this fixed the same issue for me

Comment: Somethings latency in network connectivity also causes this

Comment: Yeah. I got this error first time. Second time it worked without any change when i read this comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

Switch to the Firebase "Blaze" plan, which includes the [free usage tier of the Spark plan](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/03/adding-free-usage-to-blaze-pricing-plan.html) before incurring any costs. Use the [Blaze pricing calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/#blaze-calculator) to see what you'd be charged for a given usage.

The first 5GB of outbound (egress) networking is free, which is the same as what "native" Google Cloud Functions [would give you](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#networking).