# If I can use axios library for requesting 3rd api in firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

when I use firebase cloud functions to write a database trigger hook.
In the hook, I need to GET the api of weixin(api.weixin.qq.com) with axios, but I got an error

`getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.weixin.qq.com`

I google the error and know it's about dns. But I need to configure if I can do like using axios. Or is there alteration? Please help me, thx

Comment: Is your project on a paid plan. If not, then this is expected behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774807/firebase-functions-getaddrinfo-enotfound-api-sandbox-paypal-com

Comment: Alright, I'm a free user. Thanks, I got the solution