# Deployed Firebase Function Cannot Execute HTTP GET to external API?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-home

I am attempting to create my first Google Home Action as with the same functinality of my Amazon Alexa Skill.  The way this action works is, you execute an intent, and that calls a function in my code.  When the function is called, it sends off a GET to an external API to pull some data.

Now when I run this locally using: `firebase serve --only functions` and `ngrok`.  These will allow me to test the function on API.AI and it works fine.

But when I decide to deploy this to firebase using: `firebase deploy --only functions`, it simply does not work and throws this error:

```
error: { RequestError: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN newsapi.org:443
    at new RequestError (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (/user_code/node_modules/request/request.js:884:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:1020:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
  name: 'RequestError',
  message: 'Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN newsapi.org:443',
  cause: 
   { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN newsapi.org:443
       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
       at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
     code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
     errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: 'newsapi.org',
     host: 'newsapi.org',
     port: 443 },
  error: 
   { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN newsapi.org:443
       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
       at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
     code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
     errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: 'newsapi.org',
     host: 'newsapi.org',
     port: 443 },
  options: 
   { uri: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=hacker-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=8b87b4978b22493cadeb351cce01d52a',
     headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise' },
     family: 4,
     json: true,
     callback: [Function: RP$callback],
     transform: undefined,
     simple: true,
     resolveWithFullResponse: false,
     transform2xxOnly: false },
  response: undefined }
```

I cannot seem to find any reason why this would not work, as I can test it locally and get the data by hitting the same URL that is used in the request.  In this example, I am using `request-promise` to complete the request, but I have also used the libraries: `got`, `request`, and `https`.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: You need to be in a paid plan to make requests to external APIs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774807/firebase-functions-getaddrinfo-enotfound-api-sandbox-paypal-com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that I found for this could be that I am not using a paid Firebase plan

Comment: Is this inclusive of calling URL on a Google App Engine express URL?!

Comment: Yep, upgrading to Blaze (pay-as-you-go)  fixed it for me!