# Does Firebase blaze plan have the spark plans quota?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

Does Firebase Blaze plan have the spark plans free quota?

I want to use Firebase with google cloud platform, but would like to still have the hosting free limits. I don't care about the other services because I don't use them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update (2018-03-13): projects on the Blaze plan now get the same free quota that projects on the Spark plan get before you'll be billed for usage.

See the [blog post announcing this change](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/03/adding-free-usage-to-blaze-pricing-plan.html)

*Original answer below the fold.*

---

Whether there is a free tier on the metered Blaze plan depends on the Firebase product you use.

Firebase Hosting and Firebase Database on the Blaze plan are charged from the first byte, there is no free tier. But for example Cloud Functions for Firebase and Cloud Storage for Firebase have the same free quota on the Blaze plan as the free tier in the Spark plan.

You can most easily see this by using the [pricing calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/#blaze-calculator) at the bottom of the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

Comment: Well what about the real time databases? does it charge even if we are using just 1 database with less than 1 gb?

Comment: Realtime Database is (like Hosting) charged from the first byte when your project is on the Blaze plan.

Comment: No fair. :/ shouldn't it be spark plan + extra use cost for blaze plan. When I'm using spark we essentially don't pay a dime when using it in limits.

Comment: Now firebase Blaze plan includes Free usage from Spark plan

Comment: For those who are interested in other Firebase services, please note the subtle differences between free quotas in the Spark and Blaze, they are stated at the end of the mentioned [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/03/adding-free-usage-to-blaze-pricing-plan.html).

Comment: When I was in Spark Plan, my Hosting Storage was 10GB free. After upgrading to Blaze Plan, it drops to only 1GB free quota. After 1GB usage, Google will start to bill you, this is very discouraging indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it includes free usage from Spark plan included.
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/