# Send email nodemailer from Outlook365 erro

Tags: javascript, firebase, office365, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I'm using the firebase function to trigger the nodemailer and send an email.

Using gmail I was successful, however with Outlook365 it does not work.

My transporter

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
host: 'outlook.office365.com',
port: 25,
secure: true, // use TLS
auth: {
    user: 'myuser',
    pass: 'pass'
},
tls: {
    // do not fail on invalid certs
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}}));
```

I have tried other ports, using the service: "Outlook365", but I did not succeed.

The console always returns me the following error

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND outlook.office365.com outlook.office365.com:587
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
code: 'ECONNECTION',
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'outlook.office365.com',
host: 'outlook.office365.com',
port: 587,
command: 'CONN
```

thank's

Comment: Is your project on the free/Spark plan? If so, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774807/cloud-functions-for-firebase-getaddrinfo-enotfound

Comment: Yes, I use the free plan so probably this is the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IMAP (incoming) -> *outlook.office365.com* -> Port **993** -> SSL

SMTP (outgoing) -> *smtp.office365.com* -> Port: **587** -> TLS

I think you have port configuration error look again into this.
For more you can refer, [Configuring Your Email Client for Office 365](https://itservices.usc.edu/office365/emailclients/)

Comment: I have tried 587 port but the error continues. Apparently the problem happens because I'm using the Free / Spark plan. like Frank commented above.