# Error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND in dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have problem with this https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation tutorial. I have the same code but when I'm trying to invoke `'Weather in Moscow tomorrow'`, I get an error.

I checked the logs:

[image]

It looks like `webhook` works correctly but at the end errors occur.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cloud Functions for Firebase for your fulfillment, you'll need billing enabled on your Google Cloud project in order to make outgoing HTTP requests.

Comment: A Firebase's Blaze plan is needed as well? Please see this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774807/cloud-functions-for-firebase-getaddrinfo-enotfound