# Firestore Cloud Function - Send E-Mail onCreate with SendGrid

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I have a contact form which submits data to the Firestore Database. My intention is, that as soon as there's another entry in the collection `requests`, Firestore shall fire a function via Cloud Function, which contains the configuration for SendGrid, which again is supposed to send the data of this specific entry to an e-mail.

I've also tried to deploy this function, which was successful - but the console shows the following errors, which I reckon won't be the only one:

> Cannot read property 'requestId' of undefined

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.firestoreEmail = functions.firestore
  .document('requests/{requestId}')
  .onCreate(event => {

    const requestId = event.params.requestId;

    const db = admin.firestore();

    return db.collection('requests').doc(requestId)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {

        const requestId = event.params.requestId;

        const request = doc.data();

        const msg = {
          to: 'fuh@gmx.net',
          from: 'hello@angularfirebase.com',

          templateId: 'd-',
          substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
          substitutions: {
            name: request.name,
            lastname: request.lastname,
            email: request.email,
            package: request.package,
            date: request.date,
            text: request.text
            // and other custom properties here
          }
        };

        return sgMail.send(msg)
      })
      .then(() => console.log('email sent!') )
      .catch(err => console.log(err) )


  });
```

Edit:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.request = functions.firestore
  .document('requests/{requestId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const db = admin.firestore();

    return db.collection('requests').doc(requestId)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {

        const requestId = snap.id;

        const request = doc.data();

        const msg = {
          to: 'fuhr@gmx.net',
          from: 'hello@angularfirebase.com',

          templateId: 'd-3cd6b40ad6674f33702107d2',
          substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
          substitutions: {
            name: request.name,
            lastname: request.lastname,
            email: request.email,
            package: request.package,
            date: request.date,
            text: request.text
            // and other custom properties here
          }
        };

        return sgMail.send(msg)
      })
      .then(() => console.log('email sent!') )
      .catch(err => console.log(err) )


  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.onCreate()` method doesn't return `event`, it returns the snapshot of the object and from it you get the id of the new object.

So in your case, it has to be:

```
exports.firestoreEmail = functions.firestore.document('requests/{requestId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const requestId = snap.id; // get the id
    const db = admin.firestore();

    return db.collection('requests').doc(requestId)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
           const request = doc.data();
           const msg = {
             to: 'fuhr@gmx.net',
             from: 'hello@angularfirebase.com',

             templateId: 'd-3cd6b40ad6674f33702107d2',
             substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
             substitutions: {
                 name: request.name,
                 lastname: request.lastname,
                 email: request.email,
                 package: request.package,
                 date: request.date,
                 text: request.text
                 // and other custom properties here
             }
         };

         return sgMail.send(msg)
     })
     .then(() => console.log('email sent!') )
     .catch(err => console.log(err) )
  });
```

Comment: Just note that `functions.firestore
  .document('requests/{requestId}')
  .onCreate(event => {});`is the old syntax, for version < 1.0, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloud-firestore

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've deployed the new code and the errors on Firebase are gone, but still the email won't be send to the "to: ' '" string.

Comment: are you trying to send an email to `fuh@gmx.net` or to some dynamic email address got from firestore?

Comment: @HristoEftimov I‘m trying to send to fuh@gmx.net

Comment: @HristoEftimov The following error just showed up: ReferenceError: the event is not defined

Comment: you already have a declared `requestId`... remove the `const requestId = event.params.requestId;` in the `then()` method of the get request `db.collection('requests').doc(requestId).get()`. After the previous changes, `event` doesn't exist anymore :)

Comment: @HristoEftimov Thank's again for your help! Now there's the old error again: ReferenceError: requestId is not defined - you can see my current code in the edit above.

Comment: @TimFuhrmann in `db.collection('requests').doc(requestId)` you are passing `requestId` which is declared in the `then()` ... of course that will be undefine. You need to declare it before that... please check my updated post :)

Comment: @HristoEftimov That definetly helped, the function ended with "ok", but there is still a info:
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sendgrid.com api.sendgrid.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'api.sendgrid.com',
  host: 'api.sendgrid.com',
  port: 443 }

I think that may be why no email is being send.

Comment: I am not sure. For external request you need to turn on the paid plan. See the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42775841

Comment: @HristoEftimov I‘ll test it in near future. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it!